# Unix: Cannot create file in directory

Tags: unix

I have just reset my Mac to factory settings and now I am trying to run:
cat /dev/null > clean-os; rm clean-os

on every mounted file system to replace all empty space with hex zeroes.

```
MacBook-Pro:/ username$ cd /dev/

MacBook-Pro:dev username$ cat /dev/null > clean-os; rm clean-os

-bash: clean-os: Operation not permitted
```

I've changed the permissions of the directory via chmod so I would have thought I could write to the directory:

```
MacBook-Pro:dev username$ ls -ld
drwxrwxrwx  3 root  wheel  4282 19 Feb 14:36 .
```

I am a unix beginner but it seems the issue is on writing to the directory. No idea what to do next.

Update:

- I have tried running as sudo and it makes no difference
- I have tried changing the rights of the parent directory (/) via

  chmod g+w /
  and I get
  chmod: Unable to change file mode on /: Operation not permitted

Should I even be doing this?

Comment: General UNIX questions are not on topic here unless they're specifically about software development.

Comment: That said, MacOS (especially Catalina and later) has a number of protections restricting even root from acting in a way that would break the integrity of the system. Honestly, I'm surprised that it even let you `chmod` `/dev`.

Comment: Ok sorry about that, will bring my question somewhere else. Thanks anyway